# Matching pattern that is within brackets

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am trying to make a mobile detection class that is supposed to strip the user agent to a simple basic string like this:

> **Output:**
>   Mozilla/5.0 (*Linux x86_64*) AppleWebKit/* (KHTML, like
>   Gecko) Chrome/* Safari/*

from this:

> **Input: (HTTP_USER_AGENT)**
>   Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko)
>   Chrome/24.0.1312.69 Safari/537.17

I am using this: `/[0-9.-]{4,}/i` pattern to strip the numbers and I get:

> **RESULT OF WHERE AM I SO FAR WITH ABOVE PATTERN:**
>   Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/* (KHTML, like Gecko)
>   Chrome/* Safari/*

but my problem is how to remove the `X11;` I want a pattern that will remove everything everything after the first opening bracket and till the first empty space I think it is the right way. Acceptable alternative will be to be able to remove the brackets at all with a pattern.

Any suggestions?

PS: I am needing this to solve a problem with mobile detection and the dependency on browscap. So please no downvotes please!

PS2: the main purpose of this is to detect mobile clients and a desktop. after that I will tweak it to give information for the OS, and etc..

Comment: Maybe PHP's `get_browser()` would be helpful. [Docs here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php).

Comment: yeah it is but I am trying to implement it in a pure PHP code with a single .ini file, because not all hosting providers offer browscap installed and/or up-to-date

Comment: Can you give us some sample inputs and outputs?

Comment: @ExplosionPills done. Added what is what explanation.

Comment: What pattern are you using right now?

Comment: @ExplosionPills /[0-9.-]{4,}/i but does only the numbers

Comment: You should really use an existing tool instead of trying to re-implement your own solution. https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect seems pretty decent for mobile detection.

Comment: I suggest that you check this out: http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php . I don't think a one-size-fits-all regex solution is suitable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace **X11;** but not **KHTML**:

```
preg_replace('/\([^,)]*? ([^\)]+)/','(*\1*',$agent);
```

Explained demo here: http://regex101.com/r/vL6gT1

Comment: I believe this will help me a lot.. will test It after a hour or two and will we if It works as expected and will accept if so! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
preg_replace('/[0-9.-]{4,} #your original regex
    | # OR
    ( # start capture
       \( # open paren
    ) # end capture (so we can put the paren back)
    [^\s]+ # any number of non-space characters
    \d # a digit
    [^\s]+ # the remaining non-space characters (including other digits)
    \s # the final space
/xi', '\1', $str);
```